# IE Bug when Exporting CSV files from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a portion of the JavaScript file that generated a CSV file, which works in all browsers except IE, does anyone know of a IE fix that I can use for IE users?

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
var link = document.createElement("a");    
link.href = uri;
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";
document.body.appendChild(link);    

**//generates an IE bug
link.click();**
```

IE Error: The data area passed to a system call is too small.

```
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Please see IE Bug Screenshot
[IE Bug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7sby.png)

Comment: is the error message so complex you can't put it **in the question**? p.s. `download` property is not supported in IE, and in Edge, such code will crash Edge before version 14.14357

Comment: To get passed IE bugs when downloading things, I highly suggest using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), as a side note [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) is an extremely useful tool

Comment: Try using Blob for this.

Comment: Thanks for everyones input.

Comment: I tested this and it works in IE11
//Supports IE11
var IEwindow = window.open();
IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);IEwindow.document.close();
IEwindow.document.exec.Command('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
IEwindow.close();

Comment: However Safari is not working, and ideas?